# Is adding an Apple framework dependency increasing the app's size?

Tags: ios, frameworks

If I add a framework dependency like `SafariServices.framework`, will my app's size increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add external frameworks like from google then it increase your app size but adding apple frameworks will not increase app size.